# Registering custom property editors in spring

Tags: java, spring, propertyeditor

This is regarding Spring property editors.
I have a Interface A that is being implemented to Class B and C.
I have a command class Doc in which in which i have a list of A

```
class Doc{
List<A> list ;
}
```

list may contain either object of B or C. In this situation how could i use property editor. i wrote two property editor for the two classes and register them in initBinder method as

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(C.class,new CPropertyEditor());
 binder.registerCustomEditor(B.class,new BPropertyEditor());
```

but it does not seems to be working. Please help.

i am getting the following exception:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.test.A] for property list: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

This is my first post so please sorry if i made any mistake.

Comment: Just guessing, but since you have a List<A>, how do you expect Spring to populate it? Using Bs or Cs?

Comment: A is an interface...B and C ar its implementation classes so List can contain either B's or C's Objects.

Comment: I understand that. But if you don't care whether Spring put B or C instances in your list, what's the point in having two different implementations?

Comment: Lets say you have diffrent type of fields on you page like textfield list field...and you wanna maintain a list of fields in the class of these fields. Here is A is the field type B is textfield, C is List field and list is the list of all fields that can be on the form. isnt it the right approach?

Comment: I think i should go with BeanWrapperImpl class to find something positive. Because that class contain the logic to convert the property if necessary using the property editor.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to implement a single property editor for A.  The implementation can look at the string and then create an instance of B or C.

Comment: You are right that might be the solution. But not feasible in my case as i need to populate diffrent objcets according to the implementation. and i dont want if else code over there.